# alinear columnas de un select HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, json

estoy hacendo un formulario en web,

trato de emular un listbox, con el select html, los datos los jala, pero el problema es mostrar el contenido de los datos obtenidos, despues de pasar por html, css, php, json, js, sql server y demas hierbas, obtengo el codigo para mostrar, en el SELECT:

```
'<option value="' + filas.dni + '"   >' + filas.dni + '&nbsp&#124;&nbsp&nbsp' + filas.apellidos_nombres + ' &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&#124; ' + filas.cargo + ' &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&#124; ' + filas.sueldo +   ' &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&#124; ' + filas.costo_hora +    '</option>');
```

pero sucede que me se muestra los datos en columnas no alineadas..
ejemplo:

```
12345678 - JUAN PEREZ - MEDICO
87654321 - MARIENELLA DEL AGUILA - ENFERMERA
96325874 - PERICO PEREZ - LIMPIEZA
```

existe alguna manera de ordenarlo para que aparezca como:

```
12345678 - JUAN PEREZ                       - MEDICO
87654321 - MARIENELLA DEL AGUILA - ENFERMERA
96325874 - PERICO PEREZ                    - LIMPIEZA
```

he intentado de varias maneras:
- usando datatable de jquery, para otros usos excelente, pero, para mis objetivos se acerca mas el select
- desde el SQL server, con consultas asignado espacios a la columna, apellidos_nombres + cargo; tambien sale desalineado...

agradezco su ayuda en como alinear esas columnas en el select...

gracias..

Comment: Hola Jose, por el problema que presentas es posible que debas crear un array de tamaño fijo y reemplazar chars cuando te llegan los datos. Se me ocurre que con funciones de string de javascript se puede solucionar, igual es bastante trabajo. Buena suerte y si puedo te paso una solucion.

Comment: Hola @CristianBudzicz, agregue lo del CSS, pero igual lo centra, para salir del paso solo muestro el documento de identidad (que son formatos de numeros fijos), seguio de apellidos y nombres, despues de esta ultima columna , todo varia...solo muestro los 2 primeros...

Comment: Esta es una pregunta similar con una respuesta que publiqué, a lo mejor les sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/280766/83304

Answer (score 2):

Tienes una propiedad de `css` llamada `justify-content` que te solucionaría el problema.

Sería algo así:

```
option {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Cómo no veo mucho código supongo que esto te valdrá, aunque igual tienes alguna otra cosa que te lo puede bloquear.

Comment: hola amigo, lo agregue, pero sale todo centrado...bueno solo uestro los datos de formato fijo... gracas