# Problema con los espacios en la etiqueta Select HTML

Tags: html

Tengo el siguiente problema con los espacios de la etiqueta `Select` en **HTML** y es que debo hacer algo similar a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que el `Select` me recorta los espacios y queda todo pegado.

Intento forzarlo con un espacio en **HTML** `&nbsp;` pero igual no me queda bien.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que leas [ask] y que te hagas el [tour] para que entiendas el funcionamiento básico del sitio, te invito a que edites tu pregunta y agregues el código que has intentado utilizar para la solución de tu problema.

Comment: Buenas Oscar, agrega parte de tu codigo para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para hacer lo que deseas, puedes usar una fuente cuyos caracteres tengan todos el mismo ancho, este tipo de fuentes son denominadas [fuentes monoespaciadas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipo_de_letra_monoespaciado).

Por ejemplo, puedes ver cuando una fuente es proporcional (arriba) y cuando es tabulada (abajo):

[image: imagen de ejemplo]

Este tipo de fuentes se puede utilizar también, por ejemplo, para dar orden a operaciones matemáticas (nótese que inclusive la fuente en negrita conserva el mismo ancho que los demás caracteres):

[image: Ejemplo en operación matemática]

Siguiendo con la idea, al saber que cada letra tendrá un ancho fijo, lo que resta por hacer es contar cada cuántos caractares (valga la redundancia) inicia cada grupo de palabras. Por ejemplo:

```
SRTA. //Tenemos 6 caracteres (4 letras + 1 punto + 1 espacio)    

SRA. //Tenemos 5 caracteres, 1 menos que la palabra más larga, en ese caso debemos añadir 1 espacio adicional o &#160;
```

Para los espacios en blanco puedes usar el codificador `&#160;` el cual es un caracter de referencia numérica, o podrías usar el conocido `&nbsp;` ambos denominados ["espacios duros"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espacio_duro).

Para el ejemplo utilicé la fuente `Consolas` de Microsoft, pero podrías utilizar la que gustes del tipo `monospace`.

```css
  select {
  font-family: 'Consolas';
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">SRA.&#160;&#160;HERNANDEZ&#160;2589</option>
  <option value="saab">SR.&#160;&#160;&#160;LOPEZ&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;4785</option>
  <option value="opel">SRTA.&#160;SANCHEZ&#160;&#160;&#160;3652</option>
  <option value="audi">SRTA.&#160;GONZALEZ&#160;&#160;1452</option>
</select>
```

<sup>Fuente de las imágenes: Wikipedia.org</sup>

---

PD: Existe un componente en GitHub en el que puedes agregar columnas a elementos `select`, no lo he probado pero puede servir como segunda opción: https://github.com/RichardCollao/SelectMultiColumns

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso me soluciono todo el problema :D